# Python - How to find datetime overlapping?

Tags: python

I have duration represented as a pair of datetime objects like this

```
(datetime(2014, 1, 23, 14, 49, 6, 185955), datetime(2015, 4, 18, 14, 49, 6, 185955))
```

I have a list of such tuples like this

```
[(datetime(2014, 1, 23, 14, 49, 6, 185955), datetime(2015, 4, 18, 14, 49, 6, 185955)), (datetime(2015, 2, 2, 14, 49, 6, 185955), datetime(2015, 10, 23, 14, 49, 6, 185955)),]
```

Now how do I calculate the overlapping duration in terms of (hours, minutes, seconds) among all the durations (here pair of datetime objects) in the list?

E.g:

```
A        C                B         D    G   E          H   I     J  F
|-----------------------|
         |--------------------------|
                                             |-----------------------|
                                         |--------------|   |-----|
```

Here AB, CD are pairs of datetime objects. How do I get the overlapping CB in terms of (hours, minutes, seconds) in a
    list of such pairs?

Comment: Is there maybe anything you have tried yourself that you can share with us? It's fine if it didn't work, then we can look at how to improve it

Comment: So just substract C from B? Try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
t = [(datetime(2014, 1, 23, 14, 49, 6, 185955), datetime(2015, 4, 18, 14, 49, 6, 185955)), (datetime(2015, 2, 2, 14, 49, 6, 185955), datetime(2015, 10, 23, 14, 49, 6, 185955))]
def time_overlap(t):
    overlap = (min(t[0][1], t[1][1]) - max(t[0][0], t[1][0]))
    days = overlap.days+1
    hours, remainder = divmod(overlap.seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    hours += days*24
    return (hours,minutes,seconds)
print(time_overlap(t))
```

Output:

```
(1824, 0, 0)
```

To find overlap for multiple datetimes , do this:

```
from datetime import datetime
t = [(datetime(2014, 1, 23, 14, 49, 6, 185955), datetime(2015, 4, 18, 14, 49, 6, 185955)), (datetime(2015, 2, 2, 14, 49, 6, 185955), datetime(2015, 10, 23, 14, 49, 6, 185955))]
def time_overlap(t):
    overlap = (min([x[1] for x in t]) - max([x[0] for x in t]))
    days = overlap.days+1
    hours, remainder = divmod(overlap.seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    hours += days*24
    return (hours,minutes,seconds)
print(time_overlap(t))
```